# change orientation for android device in titanium from keyboard in MAC

Tags: android, macos, ipad, android-emulator, titanium

How do we change emulator screen orientation to landscape or portraitin titanium from keyboard in MAC?

For windows we can do this `Ctrl-F12 is the keyboard shortcut.`

I have tried this combination but no success.

```
1. window + F11
2. window + F12
3. Keypad_7
2. Keypad_9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MAC left-ctrl + F11 works for me

Answer (score 0):

After doing so many combination I tried this one and it works

```
CTRL + window + F12
```